# Add Title to Devextreme Data Grid for Excel Export

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devextreme, devexpress-mvc

I am using Devextreme js components. I am loading data to Devextreme **data grid** component and I want to add a title to show in data grid. Because when data grid are exported, I want it to show title in excel file.
I searched but I could not a property or function in js devextreme of datagrid.
I wonder is there way to add title for exported excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[dxDataGrid](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/) does not support tittles at the moment, [but they recommend you to add tittles via Html/CSS](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T356125/title-for-dxdatagrid-and-dxpivotgrid), however that way it does not get exported to excel. On the other hand these controls keep evolving, so you can look in the next release and see.

Answer (score 0):

you can give it a try by customizing your columns and can modify as per your requirements

https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/ExcelJS/NetCore/Light/